# Separating colors in ggplot to avoid fuzzyness

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

[image]

Here is a picture I generated using ggplot2 and the command I used is:

```
ggplot(dat3.prop1DF, aes(x=X1, y=value, fill=X2)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=scales::hue_pal(h = c(0,360) + 15, c=100, l=65, 
                    h.start=0, direction=1)(length(levels(dat3.prop1DF$X2)))) + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=0))
```

Unfortunately, I can't see some of the Taxon and my colors on the `geom_bar` are fuzzy. Can someone help me get clearcut colors and also ensure that l can see all my Taxa.

Thanks.

Comment: You should rethink your plot. It is very difficult to find many colours that are easy to distinguish. http://colorbrewer2.org/ has up to 12.

Answer (score 1):

As @Roland said, you are trying to put too much info into one plot. In your case using faceted plots might be a wise route to go. If I understand your plot correctly, you want to compare between the different `X1` values and also between the different `X2` value (bacteria?). Below you'll find two pieces of example code. Try them and see what suits you best.

Creating a faceted plot for each type of bacteria:

```
# example 1
ggplot(dat3.prop1DF, aes(x=X1, y=value, fill=X2)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=0)) +
  facet_wrap(~ X2)
```

Creating a faceted plot for each type of `X1` value (whatever that may be):

```
# example 2
ggplot(dat3.prop1DF, aes(x=X2, y=value, fill=X1)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=0)) +
  facet_wrap(~ X1)
```